# How to define a limited domain in coq

Tags: coq

I am trying to define a domain in the proof checker coq. How do I do this?

I'm trying to do the equivalent of `V in [0,10]`.

I've tried to do `Definition V := forall v in R, 0 <= v /\ v <= 10.`, but this lead to problems with constants like `0` not being in `V` according to Coq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple approach might be something like,

```
Require Import Omega.

Inductive V : Set :=
  mkV : forall (v:nat), 0 <= v /\ v <= 10 -> V.

Lemma member0 : V.
Proof. apply (mkV 0). omega. Qed.

Definition inc (v:V) : nat := match v with mkV n _ => n + 1 end.

Lemma inc_bounds : forall v, 0 <= inc v <= 11.
Proof. intros v; destruct v; simpl. omega. Qed.
```

Of course the type of `member0` may not be as informative as you might like. In that case, you may want to index `V` by the `nat` corresponding to each element of the set.

```
Require Import Omega.

Inductive V : nat -> Set :=
  mkV : forall (v:nat), 0 <= v /\ v <= 10 -> V v.

Lemma member0 : V 0.
Proof. apply (mkV 0). omega. Qed.

Definition inc {n} (v:V n) : nat := n + 1.

Lemma inc_bounds : forall {n:nat} (v:V n), 0 <= inc v <= 11.
Proof. intros n v. unfold inc. destruct v. omega. Qed.
```

I've not worked with `Reals` before, but the above can be implemented on `R` as well.

```
Require Import Reals.
Require Import Fourier.
Open Scope R_scope.

Inductive V : R -> Set :=
  mkV : forall (v:R), 0 <= v /\ v <= 10 -> V v.

Lemma member0 : V 0.
Proof. apply (mkV 0). split. right; auto. left; fourier. Qed.

Definition inc {r} (v:V r) : R := r + 1.

Lemma inc_bounds : forall {r:R} (v:V r), 0 <= inc v <= 11.
Proof. intros r v; unfold inc. 
  destruct v as (r,pf). destruct pf. split; fourier. 
Qed.
```

Comment: In my opinion, this answer has a small flaws.  You definitely don't want to index each element of V with its value in the set.  Also, you can use the sig type, for instance (sig (fun x :nat => x <= 10)).  Try it with check.

Answer (score 1):

I belive the natural way to do this is to use sig types, which Yves also mentions in a comment.

The elements of V will be numbers x from R, together with proofs which showsb they really should be in the set V.

```
Require Import Reals Fourier.
Open Scope R_scope.

Definition V_prop (x : R) : Prop := 0 <= x /\ x <= 10.

Definition V : Set := { x : R | V_prop x }.

Lemma V_prop0: V_prop 0.
Proof.
    unfold V_prop; split;
    [right; auto | left; fourier].
Qed.

Definition V0 : V := exist _ 0 V_prop0.
```

Comment: The `fourier` tactic is has been deprecated since Coq 8.9.0. For compatilibility reasons `fourier` is defined as a synonym for `lra` tactic (you might need to `Require Import Lra.` first).